# How to link a function to another on a custom drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I'm starting to create a custom draggable, everything seems to be fine but the shapes still doesn't move on `mousemove`, I'm confused on what I could have done wrongly, any hint to the solution would be helpful.

I guess the problem occurs on the `dragElement` function, every numbers shows correctly without an error but still nothing moves, why ?

```js
function startDrag(event) {
    var move = $(this);
    $(this).addClass('dragged-item');
    position = move.position();
    
    var lastOffset = move.data('lastTransform');
    var lastOffsetX = lastOffset ? lastOffset.dx : position.left;
    var lastOffsetY = lastOffset ? lastOffset.dy : position.top;
    
    var startX = event.pageX - lastOffsetX;
    var startY = event.pageY - lastOffsetY;
    
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', dragElement(startX, startY, event, move));
}

function dragElement(startX, startY, event, move) {
    var newDx = event.pageX - startX;
    var newDy = event.pageY - startY;
    
    move.css('transform', 'translate3d(' + newDx + 'px, ' + newDy + 'px, 0px)');
    
    // we need to save last made offset
    move.data('lastTransform', {
        dx: newDx,
        dy: newDy
    });
}


var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('element');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element= elements[i];
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
}
```

```css
.elements {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #ebeced;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.elements .element:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.elements .element {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #4dadc9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<p>Not draggable yet... 0 error on console.</p>
<div class="elements">
    <div class="element" style="transform:translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">1</div>
    <div class="element" style="transform:translate3d(50px, 100px, 0px);">2</div>
    <div class="element" style="transform:translate3d(110px, 150px, 0px);">3</div>
    <div class="element" style="transform:translate3d(150px, 240px, 0px);">4</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion on what is going wrong ?

Comment: on line 4 of your js script, i see move.poisition(),
but i cant find your declaration of this function.

here is a link to a draggable function i wrote.  
https://github.com/barrard/dragondrop/blob/master/www/js/draggable/makeDraggable.js

Comment: @Berrard it's a built-in function, https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_position.asp

Comment: I would change the code to work more with the el.style.top and el.style.left instead of using translate.

Comment: @Barrard That is exactly what I am avoiding, there are perfomance reasons why I use translate.